# cant install express and socket.io for nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, npm

PACKAGE.JSON file

```
{
    "name" : "realtimewebchat",
    "version" : "0.0.1",
    "private" : "true",
    "dependencies" : {
    "socket.io" : "0.9.16",
    "express" : "3.4.6"
    },
    "author" : "legit",
}
```

DEBUG INFO

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.14
3 info using node@v0.10.22
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 error Failed to parse json
6 error Unexpected token }
7 error File: C:\Users\Gerrerth\Desktop\chat\package.json
8 error Failed to parse package.json data.
8 error package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
8 error
8 error This is not a bug in npm.
8 error Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
9 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
10 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
11 error cwd C:\Users\Gerrerth\Desktop\chat
12 error node -v v0.10.22
13 error npm -v 1.3.14
14 error file C:\Users\Gerrerth\Desktop\chat\package.json
15 error code EJSONPARSE
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have searched for the solutions for hours from stackoverflow but still havent managed to find the right one. Could anyone recommend some tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the trailing comma on the last line:

```
{
    "name" : "realtimewebchat",
    "version" : "0.0.1",
    "private" : "true",
    "dependencies" : {
    "socket.io" : "0.9.16",
    "express" : "3.4.6"
    },
    "author" : "legit"
}
```

*Edit:* You can use [this website](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check the JSON syntax of your files.

Comment: Oh thank you. I think I even tried it before but somehow it didnt help.